# How to redraw canvas on window resize

Tags: html, canvas, resize, erase, redraw

I'm trying to redraw a canvas when the window gets resized.

At the moment when the window resizes, the canvas doesn't redraw the blue rectangle and it doesn't show the erase effect.

I'm new to canvas and I can't figure this out.

How can I fix this?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
// set the canvas element's width/height to cover #wrapper
var wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper');
var wrapperStyle=window.getComputedStyle(wrapper,null);
canvas.width=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
canvas.height=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));
//
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // set "erase" compositing once at start of app for better performance
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

var canvasOffset = $("#canvasTop").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.stroke();
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
}

$("#canvasTop").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);
 
function resizeCanvas(e) {
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
  myCanvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  myCanvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

}
```

```css
html, body {height:100%}
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#wrapper {
  position:relative; 
  margin:auto; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
#canvasTop {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
}
#text {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  width:400px; 
  height:200px; 
  text-align:center; 
  top: 50%; 
  transform:translateY(-50%); 
}
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag the mouse over center to "scratch-off" reveal</h4>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- move #text before #canvasTop -->
  <div id="text">
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvasTop" width=512 height=512></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing the canvas width or height properties will erase everything from the 2dContext. So in your case, you'll have to save all the drawn coordinates in objects somewhere and redraw them all.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, How can I do this? I'm quite new to canvas html5 and I'm not sure how to save the drawn coordinates and redraw them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to initialize your canvas and other elemnts at window.onload. 
Because at point you are initializing them, the elements on page might not be available as they've not rendered.

```
    var canvas , wrapperStyle, wrapper, ctx;
    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown = false;
    var canvasOffset, offsetX, offsetY;
    window.onload = function()
    {
         InitCanvas();
    }

    function InitCanvas()
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
        wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper');
        wrapperStyle=window.getComputedStyle(wrapper,null);
        canvas.width=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
        canvas.height=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // set "erase" compositing once at start of app for better performance
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

        canvasOffset = $("#canvasTop").offset();
        offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
        offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    }

    function resizeCanvas()
    {    
         var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
         myCanvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
         myCanvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
         InitCanvas();
    }
```

**Update 14-4-2017:**
Call resizeCanvas on body onresize.

```
    <body onresize="resizeCanvas(event)" >
```

Update: 
You might need to wire up events like this.

```
    <canvas id="canvasTop" width="512" height="512" onMouseDown="handleMouseDown(event)" onmousemove="handleMouseMove(event)" onMouseup="handleMouseUp(event)" onmouseout="handleMouseOut(event)"   ></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi @KalpeshMahajan. Thank you for this, but it doesn't seem to work. There's no erase animation.

Comment: You can use body onresize event

Comment: Hi @Kalpesh unfortunately this is still not working. It,s giving me this error: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: handleMouseMove is not defined"

Comment: For some reason I am getting same error when I tried it on jsfiddle. Check this link. https://codepen.io/kalM/pen/gWaevO

Comment: Hi @Kalpesh. Do you know if there's a way to clear the canvas when the window is smaller than 1024px? I'm trying to hide the canvas on small screens and media queries work only on window resize and not on load. I've tried adding  `if ($(window).width() > 1024) {} else {}` to function InitCanvas () but didn't work.